# Form elements rendering outside tag

Tags: php, html, laravel, bootstrap-4, adminlte

I have created a simple Bootstrap 4 modal in laravel PHP and added a form within. When I try to submit the form however, it doesn't seem to do so. After a couple of hours trying to figure out what's wrong, I think I managed to find the problem. The form elements seem to be rendering outside the `form` tag. Does anyone know the solution to this problem? Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form>
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You expect us to guess your code which generates a form? If yes - you will wait for an answer for ages.

Comment: It seems like your form contains no tags at all. Place the closing form tag at its proper position and please don't post a picture of your code.

Comment: if you dont provide code, we can't help you.

Comment: Show your code @ProblemChild

Comment: Sorry guys. I just edited and added the code. I didn't think it'll be of use, as I have even tried using a basic form by Bootstrap 4 itself and the issue still seems to exist. :(

Comment: https://jsbin.com/lajaquxeqo/1/edit?html,js,output — I can't reproduce the problem. You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: I think your html is not closed, please check your html, use this to beautify your html and it would be easy for you to find a mistake.

Comment: Hi, did you find where the issue was?

Answer (score 0):

Add `form` tag inside `modal-body` and use jquery to submit form on clicking button

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
              <form id="FormExample">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" id="SaveFormexample" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery :

```
$('#SaveFormexample').click(function() {
   $('#FormExample').submit();
});
```

Comment: The form element still seem to render outside the `form` tag.

Comment: Check your all tags if they are closing or not? @ProblemChild

Answer (score 0):

The code that you wrote is 100% working, but ...

**make sure that :**

- you closed all the "form" tags before this modal component.
- you didn't include your form inside another form tag.